# iPhone Dev: short sound and vibration at the same time

Tags: iphone, audio, vibration

is there any way to play a short sound and let the phone vibrate at the same time?
I found something about AudioQueing, but I'm a newbie and cant wrap my head around that whole process of AudioQueing.

Kind regards from Germany

Answer (score 0):

Yes. What part do you have problems with? Playing sounds, vibrating, or doing both at once? For playing short sounds you can use the [`AVAudioPlayer`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) class. The vibration is triggered by the following code:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

Described [here](http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2009/01/on-vibration.html), for example.

Comment: Tried it, but it doesn't play a sound, just produces some kind of freeze for 1-2s, then everything works like it should... But thanks, I'll have to investigate what's the problem with this freeze